# How to list all indexes/constraints/FKs in a MySQL Database from commandline

Tags: mysql, indexes

Is it possible, from the MySQL command line, to list in a single query all the indexes/constraints/FKs etc that are in the database in question?

Thanks in advance

Rich

Answer (score 1):

We can also refer to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS dictionary table providing TABLE_SCHEMA and CONSTRAINT_TYPE in where clause/

CONSTRAINT_TYPE could be 'UNIQUE'/'PRIMARY KEY'/FOREIGN KEY'

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into information_schema database, maybe these tables can help you:

- REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
- COLUMNS table (column COLUMN_KEY)